# Removing HTML tags from thousands of rows in a CSV in PIG

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs

I have a large collection of data from Stack Overflow which I obtained by querying the DB using the data explorer.

I am loading the data into HDFS and I would like to remove all HTML tags from every row of a certain column using pig.

Before loading the data I tried a Ctrl F and replace all "<*>" with "" but Excel couldn't do this for 250000 rows of data and crashed.

How could I go about doing this in PIG, so far this is what I have which is not a lot:

```
StackOverflow = load 'StackOverflow.csv' using PigStorage(',');
noHTML = FOREACH StackOverflow REPLACE(%STRING%, '<*>', '""')
```

What argument can I use in %String% to tell PIG to do this for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to the column data that needs to be modified.Assuming you have 3 columns and you would want to replace the html tags in the 2nd column,you would use the below script.$1 refers to the 2nd column

```
StackOverflow = load 'StackOverflow.csv' using PigStorage(',') 
noHTML = FOREACH StackOverflow GENERATE $0,REPLACE($1, '<*>', '') as f2_new,$1;
DUMP noHTML;
```

Or by using column names

```
StackOverflow = load 'StackOverflow.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:chararray);
noHTML = FOREACH StackOverflow GENERATE f1,REPLACE(f2, '<*>', '') as f2_new,f3;
DUMP noHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of other ways you can do it. Trying to do it in a word file wouldn't help. You need word processing. You can use perl to do this. The smartest way you can do it is using Unix/Linux tools like sed, grep etc.

```
sed -i -e 's/<string you want to delete>/""/g' filename
```